# Deeplink intent lossing urls when app is in background and process killed by Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I have recently encountered one problem by doing the following,

- Start my app
- Press home button -> app in background
- run "am kill" command from adb to kill the process (real users face it if they leave the application for hours in the background)
- Trigger the Deeplink from Chrome Browser
- The app opens but It does not take you to our desired Fragment
- If The Process is not killed by process -> it can direct to the desired fragment

My application has SingleTop as launch mode (I also tried with singleTask, it does not work). I have tested it in all OS and it happens to all of them except Android 14. In Android 14 it works in pixel 4a device

I have investigated a little bit and found out that when app is killed -> the Deeplink intent does not send it any data or ACTION_VIEW. They are all null and as my application
is checking for the intent to find the url -> it cant understand anything

FYI, I have handled the deeplink in both onNewIntent() and onCreate() of my MainActivity

Can anyone suggest me a work around?